# Scraping a site that requires login

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrapy this website: http://www.ivolatility.com/options.j?ticker=SPX&lhid=141519256 using python.

The problem is that have login and there are some issues to scrape the information. I try this code, but I didn't get the information.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

username = 'user'
password = 'pass'
scrape_url = 'http://www.ivolatility.com/options.j?ticker=SPX&lhid=141519256'

login_url = 'https://www.ivolatility.com/login.j'
login_info = {'email': username,'password': password}

#Start session.
session = requests.session()

#Login using your authentication information.
session.post(url=login_url, data=login_info)

#Request page you want to scrape.
url = session.get(url=scrape_url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: After checking the website, the parameters seem to have different names: They use `username` and `password`, not `email` and `password`. Also, they pass some additional information (`ref_url`, `steps`, `login_is_sent`. `service_name`). I am unsure, whether this additional information is required.

Comment: Thanks Leon. I change the email to username, but how can I integrate the additional information in to the script?

Comment: Assuming the information Leon mentions is required to complete a successful login, you will need to simulate it in the background. Use your browsers element inspector to examine the transactions that take place when you log in successfully. Once you know this you will be in a better position to understand what your program will need to do to effectively simulate the real world.